# Input string was not in a correct format. C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, parsing

I am putting SQL values inside  `<td>` and this line below it's causing a format error, i don't know if the parsing is incorrect or missing something. Please help

```
litAccordionFooter.Text += "<td style='width: 12.2%;font-weight: bold;'>" 
    + string.Format("{0:C}", (((ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_AMT"]))
    == DBNull.Value ? 1 
        : decimal.Parse((ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_AMT"]).ToString())) 
        / ((int.Parse((ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_QTY"]).ToString())) == 0 
            || ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_QTY"] == DBNull.Value ? 1 
                : (int.Parse((ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_QTY"]).ToString())))) + "</td>";
```

Comment: Do you have a NULL in either of those columns? Some basic debugging in c# would help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JoãoKleberson says, you should validate they are not `null` or `empty` and that they have actually a `int` and `decimal` representation

```
int     total_Amt = default(int);
decimal total_Qty = default(decimal);

if (decimal.TryParse(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_AMT"].ToString(), out total_Qty) &&
        int.TryParse(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_QTY"].ToString(), out total_Amt))
{
    var myString = "<td style='width: 12.2%;font-weight:bold;'>" +
    string.Format("{0:C}", total_Amt / total_Qty == 0 ? 1 : total_Qty) + "</td>";
}
else
{
    // The TOTAL_AMT and/or TOTAL_QTY values are not valid to convert them, 
    // verify they are not null and that they have the correct format
}
```

This way you can safety try to convert the values to the desired type, if the can't be converted the flow is going to be to the `else` clause

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this statement:
(ds.Tables [1] .Rows [0] ["TOTAL_AMT"])
(ds.Tables [1] .Rows [0] ["TOTAL_QTY"])
It is not null or empty

Comment: litAccordionFooter.Text += "<td style='width: 12.2%;font-weight: bold;'>" + string.Format("{0:C}", (((ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_AMT"])) == DBNull.Value ? 1 : decimal.Parse((ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_AMT"]).ToString())) / ((int.Parse((ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_QTY"]).ToString())) == 0 || ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_QTY"] == DBNull.Value ? 1 : (int.Parse((ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TOTAL_QTY"]).ToString())))) + "</td>";